# How select and submit data and show data from another table on the same page in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, database

When the search button is pressed, Data should be shown in the following table.

Controller

```
      public ActionResult getStudentClass(int Grade, string ABC)
      {
          // int CId;
          if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ABC))
          {
              var items = _context.Class.Where(x => x.Grade == Grade & x.ABC == ABC).ToList();
              // CId = "";
              string CId = "";

              for (int i = 0; i <= items.Count - 1; i++)
              {
                  CId += "<tr>" +
                  "<td>" + items[i].ABC + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + items[i].classId + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + items[i].classMonitor + "</td>" +
                  //"<td>" + items[i]. + "</td>" +

                  "</tr>";
              }
              TempData["Table"] = CId;
          }




          return RedirectToAction("index");
      }
```

Comment: which database u re using...?...add the tag in question

Comment: Im using SQL sever 2016

Comment: SELECT RegNo,NAME,Status FROM tbl_YourTableName WHERE Grade='1' AND Classs='A'

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow Darkside. Could you perhaps elaborate your question? As is, it is very hard to know what exact problem you are facing and therefore how to provide an answer.

Comment: use a partialview to show a new table or use Jquery to populate a pre-existing second table

Comment: I think you should simply use your index for this with optional parameters and build the table in your razor view. add the items to the viewmodel and simply display if not empty